# How to calculate the amplitude of the sum of two waves that have different amplitude?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, interference, superposition

I'm now trying to solve a problem like this.

> ($x$ denotes position and $t$ denotes time. $a_i, k, \omega, \delta_i$ are all constants.)

> Given the two waves, $u_1(x,t)=a_1 \sin (kx-\omega t + \delta_1)$ and $u_2(x,t)=a_2 \sin (kx-\omega t + \delta_2)$.
> Show that the sum of the two waves has the same angular frequency and calculate the amplitude and the phase of this wave.

I know how to calculate the amplitude and the phase of a standing wave but in this problem, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are not always equal.
I tried to prove it in the way I wrote below.

> $u_1(x,t) + u_2(x,t) = a_1 \sin (kx-\omega t + \delta_1) + a_1 \sin (kx-\omega t + \delta_2) + (a_2 - a_1) \sin (kx-\omega t + \delta_2)$

However, now I have no idea. Can anyone help me with this proof?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may apply compound angle formula to rewrite expressions for $u_1$ and $u_2$:

$$
u_1(x,t)=a_1 \sin (kx-\omega t + \delta_1) = a_1 \sin (kx-\omega t)\cos \delta_1 - a_1 \cos(kx-\omega t)\sin \delta_1 \\
u_2(x,t)=a_2 \sin (kx-\omega t + \delta_2) = a_2 \sin (kx-\omega t)\cos \delta_2 - a_2 \cos(kx-\omega t)\sin \delta_2
$$

Summing them:

$$
u_1(x,t)+u_2(x,t)=(a_1 \cos \delta_1 + a_2 \cos \delta_2) \sin(kx-\omega t) - (a_1 \sin \delta_1+a_2 \sin \delta_2) \cos(kx-\omega t)
$$

The two terms can be reduced to a single term using R-formula, that is, the following identity which holds for any $x$:
$$a \sin x - b \cos x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin\left[x-\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right]$$

So the previous sum can be reduced to:
$$\sqrt{(a_1 \cos \delta_1 + a_2 \cos \delta_2)^2 + (a_1 \sin \delta_1+a_2 \sin \delta_2)^2} \sin\left[kx-\omega t - \arctan\left(\frac{a_1 \sin \delta_1+a_2 \sin \delta_2}{a_1 \cos \delta_1 + a_2 \cos \delta_2}\right) \right]$$

From here, you may obtain the new amplitude and phase of the resulting wave. I'll leave the remaining simplification to you. For the amplitude, I believe it may be further simplified with the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is so simple that I understand it well.

Comment: @Noob4 glad it helps! do mark this as the answer if you think it answers your question :)